# How do I add all elements of a vector to every row of a table in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a vector of n length:

```
> v
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

and table:

```
> t <- data.frame(column1 = c("X", "Y"))
> head(t)

  column1
1       X
2       Y
```

How can I add the vector as a new column, such that each element of the vector is added to the already existing rows. The output I am looking is:

```
> t1 <- data.frame(column1 = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"), v = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"))
> head(t1)
  column1 v
1       X A
2       X B
3       X C
4       Y A
5       Y B
6       Y C
```

I am sure the solution is quite easy but I am struggling to phrase the question in a way that brings up the correct search results.

I have spent sometime search existing stackoverflow questions and am yet to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Something like `merge(t, as.data.frame(v))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rev(merge(list(v=v),t))
  column1 v
1       X A
2       X B
3       X C
4       Y A
5       Y B
6       Y C

rev(expand.grid(v=v,column1=t[[1]]))
  column1 v
1       X A
2       X B
3       X C
4       Y A
5       Y B
6       Y C
```